# How to create average values across variables with different suffixes?

Tags: r

I wish to learn a more efficient to get averaged values that have different suffixes, such as _L and _R.

For every brain region, I would like to create a new variable that is the averaged between the left and right hemispheres. This is denoted by the suffix `_L` and `_R`.

I am doing this manually in excel but it could be error prone.

The dataset is currently in a long format. Example: For each subject, the goal is to create a new `region` called `odi.lobar.Temporal_Average` which is the averaged of `0.030767`  and `0.371568`.

```
subject region  value
1   odi.lobar.Temporal_L    0.030767
1   odi.lobar.Temporal_R    0.371568
2   odi.lobar.Temporal_L    0.371568
2   odi.lobar.Temporal_R    0.369251
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can remove the suffix with `sub` and use `aggregate` -

```
res <- aggregate(value ~ region + subject, 
           transform(df, region = sub('_.*', '', region)), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
res
#             region subject     value
#1 odi.lobar.Temporal       1 0.2011675
#2 odi.lobar.Temporal       2 0.3704095
```

Comment: This works, thanks! How can I insert those values back into the original dataset, so that each subject now has values for `odi.lobar.Temporal_L` `odi.lobar.Temporal_R` and the new average?

Comment: You can use `rbind` - `res <- rbind(df, res)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the mean for each `subject` and if you only got one value per `subject` for each `region`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(subject = c("1","1","2","2"),
                 region = c("odi.lobar.Temporal_L","odi.lobar.Temporal_R","odi.lobar.Temporal_L","odi.lobar.Temporal_R"),
                 value = c(0.030767,0.371568,0.371568,0.369251))
```

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
output <- df %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarise(odi.lobar.Temporal_Average= mean(value))
```

Output:

```
  subject odi.lobar.Temporal_Average
  <chr>                        <dbl>
1 1                            0.201
2 2                            0.370
```

Edit: If you want to keep initial data:

```
output <- df %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarise(odi.lobar.Temporal_Average = mean(value))%>% 
  pivot_longer(odi.lobar.Temporal_Average) %>% 
  rename(region = name) %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  arrange(subject)
```

Output:

```
  subject region                      value
  <chr>   <chr>                       <dbl>
1 1       odi.lobar.Temporal_Average 0.201 
2 1       odi.lobar.Temporal_L       0.0308
3 1       odi.lobar.Temporal_R       0.372 
4 2       odi.lobar.Temporal_Average 0.370 
5 2       odi.lobar.Temporal_L       0.372 
6 2       odi.lobar.Temporal_R       0.369
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  separate(region, c("region", "side"), sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(subject, region = paste0(region, "_Average")) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  bind_rows(df1)


# A tibble: 6 x 3
  subject region                      value
    <int> <chr>                       <dbl>
1       1 odi.lobar.Temporal_Average 0.201 
2       2 odi.lobar.Temporal_Average 0.370 
3       1 odi.lobar.Temporal_L       0.0308
4       1 odi.lobar.Temporal_R       0.372 
5       2 odi.lobar.Temporal_L       0.372 
6       2 odi.lobar.Temporal_R       0.369
```